# ImageView within an AbsoluteLayout, How to set x, y coordinates of the ImageView?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, absolutelayout

What I'm trying to do is create a poorman's version of a gps map. I've setup a "map" picture as the background of an AbsoluteLayout, and then created a tiny 20x20 square picture that I need to move to different coordinates. How do I go about doing this in the Java code?

```
 <AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/llMapContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="390dp"
    android:layout_x="0dp"
    android:layout_y="44dp"
    android:background="@drawable/a4000vert"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLocation"
        android:layout_width="20px"
        android:layout_height="20px"
        android:layout_x="312px"
        android:layout_y="300px"
        android:src="@drawable/location" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

I have this setup in my Java file:
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLocation);

but now I can't seem to find any methods that would allow me to set the x and y coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

`AbsoluteLayout` is depreciated and its use is strongly discouraged. You should switch to using some other form of `ViewGroup`, such as `RelativeLayout`.

Once you're using `RelativeLayout`, you can use the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` class to specify the child's size and position (as well as various other parameters) when adding it to the parent `RelativeLayout`.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,200); // The desired size of the child
params.setMargins(50,50); // Position at 50,50
mRelativeLayout.addView( mViewToAdd, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can set x and y coordinates of your `ImageView` inside the `AbsoluteLayout`:

```
private void setLocation(int x, int y) {
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLocation);
    final AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams lp = (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) iv.getLayoutParams();
    lp.x = x;
    lp.y = y;
    iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

I agree with Trevor though that you might want to avoid using `AbsoluteLayout` if possible since it has been deprecated.