# Move an image inside a webview android

Tags: android, webview

In my layout i have an ImageView inside a WebView and coordinates.  I want to set the image position programmatically using based on WebView x and y coordinates.  Is it possible to achieve this and how.  Or give me a tutorial to follow.

Answer (score 0):

First of all tell do you have exactly

```
ImageView inside a WebView
```

or just image inside a page in WebView?

If you still looking for ImageView moving check this answer [ImageView within an AbsoluteLayout, How to set x, y coordinates of the ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360312/imageview-within-an-absolutelayout-how-to-set-x-y-coordinates-of-the-imageview)

If it's just html  use js to move it :) But remember to switch it on!

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: i have specific dynamic region set inside mywebview and an imageview to appear inside the region onclick