# Re-initialise position of ImageButton in Android

Tags: android, imagebutton

In this problem i wanted to change the position of the ImageButton frequently. After the first initialization the ImageButton is not changing its position.
Here is the code...

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<60;i++)
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
                img.refreshDrawableState();

                Random r=new Random();
                int a=r.nextInt();
                int b=r.nextInt();

                if(a<0)
                    a=a*(-1);
                if(b<0)
                    b=b*(-1);

                w=(a%(width-50))-72;
                h=(b%(height-50))-30;



                img.refreshDrawableState();
                img.setLeft(w);
                img.setTop(h);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "width : "+w+"\theight : "+h, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

The variables height & width are height & width of the screen

Comment: Is your imagebutton in a AbsoluteValue layout?

Comment: @wyoskibum : It is in the RelativeLayout.

Comment: Then it's logical that you button doens't move.. the relativelayout works as designed

Comment: @user1281750 : then which layout should i use ?

Comment: Learn about the different types of viewgroups here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html
(different types of viewgroups can be selected in the known subclasses item). If you want to use x,y coordinates then absoluteLayout will the way to go, but this is not the android way (not anymore atleast hence it deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an Absolute Layout and set the layout parameters.  I found this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360312/imageview-within-an-absolutelayout-how-to-set-x-y-coordinates-of-the-imageview) useful when I needed to do something similar.

Comment: I have tried as the above link says, but the problem still persists.